# How to multiply vector to create a matrix?

Tags: matrix

There might be related posts but so far I'd not been able to find them:

```
u={u1,u2,u3}
v={v1,v2,v3}
```

where $u$ and $v$ are two column vectors. I want to use $u\times v^T$ to create a matrix, where $\times$ represent matrix multiplication, and $v^T$ represent the transpose of the $v$, which was a row vectors.

Is there any easy way to do that?
I have tried Matrixform, array, .,$\times$/Cross[] functions, but so far non of them worked.

Comment: `Outer[Times, u, v]`

Comment: For long, numerical vectors, `KroneckerProduct[u,v]` is usually faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Outer[Times, u, v]`. See [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html).

If you want to use the matrix multiplication notation, you need to turn these vectors (one-index tensors) into matrices (two-index tensors):

```
Transpose[{u}].{v}
```